# Changing an element in an array in C and Getting both old and new element as output

Tags: arrays, c

Firstly I created an array and accessed an element of it. After that, I tried to change that array element without removing the access part and I got both new and old elements as the output. How can I get only the new element as the output? I am beginner for the C language.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int myfirstarray[] = {2,50,16,100,39};
    printf("%d",myfirstarray[2]);
    myfirstarray[2]=78;
    printf("%d",myfirstarray[2]);

}
```

this is the code and,

```
1678
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 4.098 s
Press any key to continue.
```

this is what I got.

I want to get output as only 78

Comment: Remove the first printf line.  What am I  missing?

Comment: Perhaps you want to check how you can print a line ending :-) or a space or other forms of whitespace. Using printf, you don't get them for free.

Comment: You print `"16"` and then without any whitespace you also print `"78"`. That results in `"1678"` on your screen. The second `printf` does not make the output from first one disappear. Add spaces, line breaks etc. to separate them. Or don't print the first value if you don't want to get it.

Answer (score 0):

When a program executes, each print statement writes a new string (or chunk of characters) to the output stream according to format string. These accumulate.

After the execution of:

```
int myfirstarray[] = {2,50,16,100,39};
printf("%d",myfirstarray[2]);
```

Output  (after execution of the second line):

```
16
```

Then, the value is changed and a new chunk is produced for the second index:

```
myfirstarray[2]=78;
printf("%d",myfirstarray[2]);
```

Output (after execution of the fourth line):

```
1678
```

This is analogous to the following:

```
printf("word:\n");
printf("mor");
printf("pho");
printf("graphic\n");
```

Output:

```
word:
morphographic
```